# Trying to make trigger with merge statement functional

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2019

As the title says I'm trying to find the best way to refractor my code to work and fix the syntax that throws error in SQL Server 2019. I have tried removing cases keywords, putting all when statements inside a single case keyword and also putting every when statement within their specific case but every time it gives me an error on the line where I want to delete the row.

Here is my code for a better understanding.

```
CREATE trigger afterSalary
on Salary
Instead Of Insert
as
Begin
    Select P.Id, P.Valid_From, P.Valid_To 
into #TempTable
from Salary as P JOIN
inserted as I on S.Employee_ID = I.Employee_ID
WHERE S.Valid_From BETWEEN I.Valid_From AND I.Valid_To
or S.Valid_To BETWEEN I.Valid_From AND I.Valid_To

    MERGE Salary AS Pl
    USING #TempTable AS Tt
    ON (Pl.ID = Tt.ID)
    WHEN MATCHED AND
        CASE
            WHEN (Pl.Valid_From BETWEEN Tt.Valid_From AND Tt.Valid_To)
                and (Pl.Valid_To BETWEEN Tt.Valid_From AND Tt.Valid_To)
                THEN DELETE
        END
        CASE
            WHEN Pl.Valid_To > inserted.Valid_From
                THEN UPDATE SET Pl.Valid_To = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, Inserted.Valid_From));
        END
        CASE
            WHEN Pl.Valid_From < Inserted.Valid_To
            THEN UPDATE SET Pl.Valid_From = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, +1, Inserted.Valid_To));
        END
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Tt
        THEN INSERT (Employee_ID, Valid_From, Valid_To) VALUES (Tt.Employee_ID, Tt.Valid_From, Tt.Valid_To);    
END
```

So I can't figure it out why those case statements "then delete" to be precise gives me syntax error.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure afterSalary, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 12]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DELETE'.

Here is my Salary table before insert statement:

```
ID : 1, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2020/02/01, Valid_To : 2020/02/04
ID : 2, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2020/02/05, Valid_To : 2020/11/23
ID : 3, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2020/11/24, Valid_To : 2021/06/01
ID : 4, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2021/06/02, Valid_To : 2021/09/17
```

After I insert new salary for Employeed with ID 1 like this:

```
INSERT INTO Salary (Employee_ID, Valid_From, Valid_To)
VALUES (1, '2020/11/24', '2021/08/06')
```

I want my salary table after insert to look like:

```
ID : 1, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2020/02/01, Valid_To : 2020/02/04
ID : 2, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2020/02/05, Valid_To : 2020/11/23
ID : 5, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2020/11/24, Valid_To : 2021/08/06
ID : 4, Employee_ID : 1, Valid_From : 2021/08/07, Valid_To : 2021/09/17
```

Comment: Why do you want MERGE? Please read all these links: https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm pretty confused with some english words but yea I still don't get it why would it give me wrong syntax error.

Comment: I need to use merge for existing Salary table when I want to insert salary for specific employee that it has to check for overlappign salaries and delete or update them

Comment: My previous comment about case being an expression not a statement is the cause of your error. I recommend reading the docs, case can return a value, not provide conditional code execution (like a switch can).

Comment: Aarons point is you can accomplish that without a merge, and maybe more safely.

Comment: More on Dale's point about CASE not being for control of flow here: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression

Comment: Instead of showing us your trigger code, why don't you show us the salary table, a few rows, and inserts that later come in and how you want the table to look like after each attempted insert. With just the trigger code I'm having a hard time understanding how something overlaps, which rows to delete or update, and whether it's based on ID or Employee_ID (what is the point of two ID columns?) Also it is interesting to me that you have a table called `Salary` but these inserts don't contain, uh, salary.

Comment: Basically in my first selection I select all the rows that have to be deleted or have only one column changed. Then in merge I compare all matching rows, if they need to be deleted they're removed in first case expression, if I need to delete only one column then it has to go through proper column checking and update only single column. If there is no match I just insert my new value as usual

Comment: The records don't have to be exactly as in my table, they can be arranged by ids as follows 1, 2, 4, 5. The most important thing is to have salaries organized so they happen just  one day after previous sallary valid to period.

Comment: Why are you using a temp table, you could just put it in a CTE on the `MERGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each when clause can only result in a single action.  Adding a CASE with multiple actions breaks that rule.  But the good news is you can have multiple 'WHEN MATCHED' clauses with different conditions and multiple results.  So basically what you have here:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND
    CASE
        WHEN (Pl.Valid_From BETWEEN Tt.Valid_From AND Tt.Valid_To)
            and (Pl.Valid_To BETWEEN Tt.Valid_From AND Tt.Valid_To)
            THEN DELETE
    END
    CASE
        WHEN Pl.Valid_To > inserted.Valid_From
            THEN UPDATE SET Pl.Valid_To = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, Inserted.Valid_From));
    END
```

becomes:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND (Pl.Valid_From BETWEEN Tt.Valid_From AND Tt.Valid_To)
            and (Pl.Valid_To BETWEEN Tt.Valid_From AND Tt.Valid_To) 
THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND Pl.Valid_To > inserted.Valid_From
            THEN UPDATE SET Pl.Valid_To = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, Inserted.Valid_From)
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm lookin for ty

Comment: No the only thing that's not working is that I can't use matched more than once inside merge